# How can I change the URL from localhost to a non-local host when I receive an email in Maildev to change the password?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache, deployment

I'm using Maildev to test the reception of emails, for example in my case locally if I forget my password I receive a message with the link: http://localhost:8080/login/reset.I have deployed my application on azure but when I test the reception of emails in case of forgetting the password I receive the same path http://localhost:8080/login/reset/ and the link don't work. How can I configure the path to be able to test the change of password for the application deployed on azure ?

I tried to see the configuration on the Apache conf of the proxy in the virtualhost (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/) but unfortunately I don't know too much about it. Can you please guide me on it ?

Comment: Where is maildev getting the localhost url from? Is it passed to maildev from spring?

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors/text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)